# How to remove new line from the string in awk?

Tags: shell, awk

data test.txt

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
a,s,f
```

Script

```
#!/bin/bash
a=test.txt

cat $a | awk -F , '{ print system("uuidgen"),$1,$3 }' > output.txt
```

Output

```
772c2c75-fbd6-42db-80eb-839a4817178a
a,c
c1293427-4ec1-4b28-ac47-3a22dc30037b
1,3
f8da702d-2411-4e9c-9c28-123793a9f44b
a,f
```

It automatically break into new line.

Output should be like this

```
772c2c75-fbd6-42db-80eb-839a4817178a,a,c
c1293427-4ec1-4b28-ac47-3a22dc30037b,1,3
f8da702d-2411-4e9c-9c28-123793a9f44b,a,f
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `getline` instead of `system` to capture command's output in a variable:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} ("uuidgen" |& getline out) > 0 {
       print "\"" out "\"", $1, $3; close("uuidgen")}' test.txt
29F8159A-F3F0-41B4-AE8B-6B86562FE58B,a,c
29F8159A-F3F0-41B4-AE8B-6B86562FE58B,1,3
29F8159A-F3F0-41B4-AE8B-6B86562FE58B,a,f
```

Comment: thnks@anubhava i have question I want to put double quotes on "29F8159A-F3F0-41B4-AE8B-6B86562FE58B" plz let me know.

Comment: You can then use: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} { "uuidgen" |& getline out; print "\"" out "\"", $1, $3 }' test.txt`

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton for the sound advise. It is corrected now.